# Find the equation of the tangent line of $y=x^2-x$ at $(-2,6)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I got the derivative $2x-1$ but I don't know where to go from there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want find a line. you have a point and you need the slope so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the slope of the tangent is the derivative of the function at point $(x_1, y_1)$, which is said to be $(-2, 6)$.
$$f’x = 2x-1$$
$$ m = f’(x_1)$$
$$m = 2\cdot(-2)-1$$
$$\implies \boxed{m = -5}$$
Now, we have the slope, and we have a point. Therefore, we’ll use point-slope form to find the equation of the tangent line.
$$y-y_1 = m\cdot(x-x_1)$$
$$y-6 = -5\cdot(x-(-2))$$
$$y-6 = -5\cdot(x+2)$$
$$y-6 = -5x-10 \implies \boxed{y = -5x-4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try point-slope form: $ y-y_0=m(x-x_0) $

Answer (score 0):

Slope is $2x - 1$ when $x = -2$

Slope $= -4 - 1 = -5$

$y = -5x + b$

$6 = -5(-2) + b$

$b = -4$

Tangent is $y = -5x - 4$